# .NET simplify complex generic type

Tags: c#, class, generics, refactoring

I have this code:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<char, ClassA>>();
```

I think, it's code is not so good, and i want to simplify generic type for dictionary everywhere. So i do like this:

```
class ClassB : Dictionary<char, ClassA> {}
```

So i have for now:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, ClassB>();
```

This is much more pretty code in my opinion.

But i want to know, is this right practice to declare empty class for this puproses?

Comment: If it improves readability - it's a good practice. Moreover, it allows abstraction wchich is also good. Make sure you name it properly.

Comment: @PawełDyl Thanks, can you remake your comment as answer for closing this question?

Comment: For a better abstraction and loose coupling, you could even change `ClassB` to`InterfaceB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it improves readablility - it's a good practice. Moreover, it allows abstraction which is also good. You can, in the future, add some methods to `ClassB` without breaking all the code. Make sure to *name it properly*. It makes clear, what dictionary do / what is for.